# Deciphering 1910 Russian city name?

Tags: palaeography, poland, russia, 1910s, manifest

On a 1909 passenger list I have the following record. The 1st word is the city name. There is a ditto mark to the left of that, it is for Russia. To the right of the city name it says Father Jozef Obuchowski, then it looks like city name again, then something and then Russia. To the right of this is Minn and St. Paul.

Can you help deciphering any of this?

[image: snippet from passenger list]

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  You didn't say what the column heading were for the information shown. Presumably this comes from the questions for the last residence in Russia, the nearest relative in the country of origin, and to the right, the destination city in the USA.

Comment: Yes I should have added column headings. They are “Country” which in snippet is just ditto marks for Russia; City or town which responders have put forth an answer I believe is correct;  then “name and complete address of nearest relative or friend in country which alien came” ; then last two are final destination state and town. Also I should clarify that “Father” in my inquiry references “parent” not a priest

Comment: Yes, my comment was intended to add context for the readers who aren't familiar with US immigration forms.

Answer (score 5):

The name appears to be written as "***Dovgirdeli***" or "***Dowgirdeli***".

However, this will have been an attempt to render a Russian/Polish/Lithuanian name into English so we shouldn't expect that the spelling will necessarily exactly match the original place-name!

---

I found this [List of inhabited places of Suwalki governorate](https://gen.wooyd.org/suwalki/) which includes the following place name:

- Location name (Lithuanian phonetic equivalent): **Dovgirdele**
- Original record (including alternative names): **Довгирделе**
- [Gmina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmina): **Olita**
- Alternative spellings (automatically generated): **Dovgirdele, Довгирделе**

(The *Governate* and *Gmina* both match information in the second column of your snippet, about Father Jozef Obuchowski.)

---

According to Polish Wikipedia (with the help of Google translate), [Gmina Olita](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmina_Olita) is now part of Lithuania.  In fact (also from Polish Wikipedia), most of the former [Suwałki Governorate](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gubernia_suwalska) is now part of Lithuania, apart from the southwestern part which remains part of Poland, and several municipalities from the former *Augustów poviat* which are today part of Belarus.

---

Searching Google for `Довгирделе` resulted in half-a-dozen or so books which I am unable to read, but which may help with your research.